# Using a for loop in R with a condition

Tags: r, for-loop, bioinformatics

I am trying to write a rscript that will find the annotation for ChIP-seq peaks using biomaRt from the bioconductor package.  I am adapting the annotation code from here, https://sites.google.com/a/brown.edu/bioinformatics-in-biomed/spp-r-from-chip-seq I need to find TSS sites within 2.5 to 5kb of the binding peak. Unlike in the example website, I have to do it across the entire genome.

I know that the code works for annotation - currently, I have the code block duplicated 22 times instead of with the loop.

I also need to find away to keep the script from exiting if there are no peaks on the chromosome that is being iterated over.

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript --vanilla --slave

# Change to data directory
setwd("/data/met/bowtie_out/tAfiles/MLE15/2/");

# send the output to a file AND the Terminal
sink("09June2013_spp.txt", append=FALSE, split=TRUE);

# Load Libraries
library(biomaRt);
library(plyr);

load("MLE15_pooled_2.Rdata");

# y equals the SPP score. I have to truncate it after IDR analysis.

bp <- llply(region.peaks$npl, subset, y > 12.0633)

print(paste("After filtering",sum(unlist(lapply(bp,function(d) length(d$x)))),"peaks remain"));

save.image(file="09Jun13_1.RData");

# begin collecting annotation have to use mm10.

ensembl= useMart('ensembl', dataset='mmusculus_gene_ensembl', host="apr2013.archive.ensembl.org");

# need to make a for loop that will loop through all of the chromosomes and not error out if no peaks are on that chromosome.

# So for this 'for' loop in R do I need to make a list? like for (z in (c('1'....etc?

for ( z in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', 'X', 'Y', 'M' ) {

# To insert the variable which I am looping on with other variables, is there something I should add like the $ in bash for loops that is specific to R? can I put the variable in quotes - like for the input to biomaRt? ex. values= "z"?

genes.chrz = getBM(attributes = c("chromosome_name", "start_position", "end_position", "strand", "description", "entrezgene"), filters = "chromosome_name", values= "z", mart = ensembl);

overlap = function(bs, ts, l)
{
    if ((bs > ts - l) && (bs < ts + l)) {
        TRUE;
    } else {
        FALSE;
    }
}

fivePrimeGenes = function(bs, ts, te, s, l, n, c, d)
{
    fivePrimeVec = logical();
    for (i in 1:length(ts)) {
            fivePrime = FALSE;
            for (j in 1:length(bs)) {
                if (s[i] == 1) {
                    fivePrime = fivePrime || overlap(bs[j], ts[i], l);
                } else {
                    fivePrime = fivePrime || overlap(bs[j], te[i], l);
                }
             }
            fivePrimeVec = c(fivePrimeVec, fivePrime);
    }
     fivePrimeVec;
}

fivePrimeGenesLogical = fivePrimeGenes(bp$chrz$x, genes.chrz$start_position, genes.chrz$end_position, genes.chrz$strand, 5000, genes.chrz$entrezgene, genes.chrz$chromosome_name, genes.chrz$description);
fivePrimeStartsPlus = genes.chrz$start_position[fivePrimeGenesLogical & genes.chrz$strand == 1]
fivePrimeStartsMinus = genes.chrz$end_position[fivePrimeGenesLogical & genes.chrz$strand == -1]
fivePrimeStarts = sort(c(fivePrimeStartsPlus, fivePrimeStartsMinus));

entrezgene <- data.frame(genes.chrz$entrezgene[fivePrimeGenesLogical]);
chromosome_name <- data.frame(genes.chrz$chromosome_name[fivePrimeGenesLogical]);
start_pos <- data.frame(genes.chrz$start_position[fivePrimeGenesLogical]);
end_pos <- data.frame(genes.chrz$end_position[fivePrimeGenesLogical]);
strand <- data.frame(genes.chrz$strand[fivePrimeGenesLogical]);
description <- data.frame(genes.chrz$description[fivePrimeGenesLogical]);


AnnotationData <- cbind(chromosome_name, entrezgene, start_pos, end_pos, strand, description);
write.table(AnnotationData, file="chrz_annotation_data.csv", row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, sep="\t");

}

save.image(file="09Jun13_2.RData");

# close the output file
sink()

# clean all
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE));

quit("yes");
```

Sorry to make such a messy question, but I figure that having the lines out there will help other people who are trying to annotate their peak files. Any help or advice is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Truly a mess. But here's a tip: try `for( z in c(as.character(1:19),"X","Y","M") )`.

Comment: For the sake of brevity, change your for-loop call to `for(z in c(1:19,"X","Y","M"))`.

Comment: you can also take the function declaration out of the loop.

Comment: Ok, thanks Thomas. Haki which function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's get the annotations; no need to loop over chromosomes at this stage

```
library(biomaRt)
ensembl <- useMart('ENSEMBL_MART_ENSEMBL', dataset='mmusculus_gene_ensembl',
                   host="apr2013.archive.ensembl.org")
genes.chrz <- getBM(attributes = c("chromosome_name", "start_position",
                      "end_position", "strand", "description", "entrezgene"),
                    mart = ensembl)
```

It'll be convenient to use functions from the *GenomicRanges* package, and in particular to represent our annotations (and our data) as a `GRanges` object.

```
library(GenomicRanges)
genes <- with(genes.chrz, {
    GRanges(chromosome_name, IRanges(start_position, end_position), strand, 
            entrezgene=entrezgene, description=description)
})
```

Looks like you're interested in the 5000 nt flanking (5' of) the start of each gene

```
flanks <- flank(genes, 5000)
```

Looks like you have some peak data that is in a data frame that you could make into a `GRanges` object; it's too hard to tell from what you've provided. Then it's easy to, e.g., count the number of peaks overlapping each flanking region or subset the peaks to contain just those that overlap flanking regions.

```
gr <- with(df, GRanges(chrom, IRanges(start, end), strand))
countOverlaps(flanks, gr)
subsetByOverlaps(gr, flanks)
```

There are extensive vignettes available from the [GenomicRanges](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/GenomicRanges.html) and [IRanges](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/IRanges.html) landing pages; the [Bioconductor](http://bioconductor.org/help/mailing-list/mailform/) mailing list is a helpful resource.

But if one really wants to work with the code Matt provides... I started by zapping all those ';' (not needed in R) and wrapping the code to 80 columns for readability. Then I pulled the constant function definitions outside the loop and revised `overlap` to operate on a vector `ts`, rather than a scalar

```
overlap = function(bs, ts, l)
{
    ## suppose ts is a vector, bs and l scalars, then use single '&';
    ## result is a logical(length(ts)) with appropriate values TRUE or
    ## FALSE
    (bs > ts - l) & (bs < ts + l)
}
```

for `fivePrimeGenes` I tried to exploit the vectorized `overlap` -- I don't have to iterate over `ts`, just invoke `overlap` once for each `bs[j]`. There are more efficient ways of doing this... I used `seq_along` so that I don't get caught by doing `1:0` when `bs` is of length 0, and removed arguments not used in the function

```
fivePrimeGenes = function(bs, ts, te, s, l)
{
    ## use 'pre-allocate and fill' rather than copy-and-append
    fivePrimeVec <- logical(length(ts)) # initially all FALSE
    ## choose strand for all elements of ts, te;
    se <- ifelse(s == 1, ts, te)
    ## overlap is vectorized, no need to iterate over elements of se
    ## use seq_along() to avoid edge case of 0-length ts
    for (j in seq_along(bs))
        ## calculate overlaps for each element of bs
        fivePrimeVec <- fivePrimeVec | overlap(bs[j], se, l)
    fivePrimeVec
}
```

OK, for the main loop, let R create the sequence 1:19, and coerce to character. Use the variable `z` rather than the string "z" when querying biomaRt, and when creating a file name to write data to. Use of `with` is a convenience / evil; it helped to tidy the code in this case so I chose to use it. `fivePrimeStarts` was not used in subsequent calculations, so I removed it. Seemed like AnnotationData could be created as a subset of the existing data frame, rather than error-prone assembly from subset parts.

```
for ( z in c( 1:19, "X", "Y", "M" ) )  {
    ## use the variable z, rather than the string "z"; order
    ## attributes as wanted in final representation
    attributes <- c("entrezgene", "chromosome_name", "start_position",
                    "end_position", "strand", "description",
                    "entrezgene")
    genes.chrz = getBM(attributes = attributes,
      filters = "chromosome_name", values=z, mart = ensembl)

    ## use 'with' to simplify common column selection
    fivePrimeGenesLogical = with(genes.chrz, {
        fivePrimeGenes(bp$chrz$x, start_position, end_position, strand, 5000)
    })

    ## AnnotationData as subset, rather than assembling
    AnnotationData <- genes.chrz[fivePrimeGenesLogical,, drop=FALSE]
    ## as a matrix? as.matrix(AnnotationData)

    ## use 'sprintf' to create a file name
    write.table(AnnotationData,
                file=sprintf("chr%s_annotation_data.csv", z),
                row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, sep="\t")
}
```

I hope that helps; probably I introduced a lot of errors!

Comment: Thanks Martin. I am able to get it working just fine, just duplicated 22 times in the script. I guess I should have put in a question more directed toward loops in R.

Comment: I guess the loop isn't necessary, and as written VERY inefficient; avoid all the trouble by working on vectors without looping, and using existing packages like GenomicRanges that are designed for the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @MattThornton I added to my answer, working with your code; probably the answer you were looking for is in getBM and write.table lines, but hopefully the other suggestions also help.